# What are the precautions/steps that I must take to install Ubuntu on a FreeDOS laptop?

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I am buying a Lenovo G500s laptop with FreeDOS (I opted for it). I want to install Ubuntu on it. Will there be any problem in this case? My laptop configuration is Intel core i5 3rd generation processor, 8GB RAM, 2GB Nvidia GeForce graphics, 500GB hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which you may have problems with is the Graphics Card, it will most likely work, however you may need to play with the drivers and select a different one from the System Settings> Updates and files>Other Drivers

or from the Terminal:

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

I suggest if there are options here to change the driver, that you choose the latest version first and work downwards until you find one that works well with your setup.